# Solr: Reverting back to an old schema and stop reindexing

Tags: solr, lucene, reindex

I accidently stoped an instance of Solr on my server that hat a symbolic link to a newer schema than it was using while running. Upon restarting the server solr started reindexing the documents to reflect the changes in the new schema.xml. I however did not want that and want to stop the reindexing and change back to my old schema.

The question: Does anyone know if stoping the solr server now (while it is reindexing), changing back the old schema and starting the server again will reindex only the newly reindexed files back to the old schema or will the reindexing run for all documents? The problem is that I have a couple of GB worth of data and reindexing all documents to the new schema will take many days....

Currently i would say about 2% or so are reindexed to the schema.xml after 5 hours. So if i can change back these 2% in 5 hours would be great instead of waiting for the the other 98%. If of course changing back to the old schema means that i need to reindex the 2% and the other 98% that are still in the old schema i have no benifit of changing it.

I can't find any info on the web about it, i guess it is uncommen to have so much data that reindexing requires many days...

This question goes into a similar direction but does not answer if the reindexing is smart enough to skip all other documents:
[Does schema change require reindex of all Solr documents or just documents containing the changed schema fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071377/does-schema-change-require-reindex-of-all-solr-documents-or-just-documents-conta)

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who may run into the same issue, turns out that when you stop a reindexing process (by stoping the server) and start it again with the original old schema it will only reindex the few documents that where changed by the newer schema and skip everything else and leave it as is.

After that i suggest running an optimization from the webadmin panel to get rid of the dead docs

Smart Solar :)